# how to compare this format in php ? 30-APR-12 03.46.59.000000000 PM?

Tags: php, oracle

how to compare this date format in PHP ? 30-APR-12 03.46.59.000000000 PM

Comment: You could create a DateTime object from that format and then get the date in any format you want - http://us2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: @DanLaManna You should write that as an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a DateTime object from that format and then get the date in any format you want - https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

you could use the DateTime function `createfromformat()` ([here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)) . If you make a timestamp out of that (using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) or [getTimeStamp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)) it is easy to compare to other timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the last 9 digits are for. If it's milli seconds php supports just up to 6 digits with *u* thats why I'd used * to drop the last digits.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-y H.i.s.u*', '30-APR-12 03.46.59.000000000 PM');
```

Further information can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php